# Android source code for Adding two number without button control?

Tags: android

In android it  possible that add two numbers without using the button press. can any suggestion for that.

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question".

Comment: sounds like you should follow some basic programming tutorials. that will save you frustration in the future too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not interested in performing any UI actions, then place the addition code in onCreate() callback method and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use a menu item to perform this action. On this way, you don't need use button widget.

On your activity code, search by onOptionsItemSelected method and write your sum code.

Best regards!